# Olimexino 32u4: Wire.endTransmission() hangs

Tags: i2c, wire-library

I'm trying to get a TAE5767 (FM radio) to work. According to [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/TEA5767-FM-Radio-Breakout-Board-for-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS) I'm trying it on a 5V-Olimexino 32u4 (Leonardo-compatible) with following code (Arduino 1.6.3):

```c
#include <Wire.h>

void setFrequency(float frequency) {
  unsigned int frequencyB = 4 * (frequency * 1000000 + 225000) / 32768;
  byte frequencyH = frequencyB >> 8;
  byte frequencyL = frequencyB & 0xFF;
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x60); 

  Wire.write(frequencyH);
  Wire.write(frequencyL);
  Wire.write(0xB0);
  Wire.write(0x10);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Serial.println("sending");
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Serial.println("sent");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
  }

  Wire.begin();
  setFrequency(89);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Unfortunately, it only prints

```
sending
```

First, I thought I'd damaged my chip, but I'm now using the second with the same result. I've also tried the I2C-Scanner from [Nick Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c), but it prints nothing. I've tried adding 2.2k resistors from SCL and SDA to 5V without success. Does someone has a clue what I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've did not got it working with `Wire`. Hence I've implemented a I2C protocol myself using bit-banging and then it works.

**Update from 2017-September-16**

The problem was not `Wire.h` but a specialty of the Olimexino 32u4 board. I've only found out by using a Real Time Clock connected to the UEXT port's I2C bus, that I have to switch on the power for the UEXT port by setting D8 to LOW. Otherwise SDA or SCL seem to be pulled down preventing any I2C communication.